# Problem in Spying of web applications in Blue prism

Tags: blueprism, rpa

I am unable to highlight the elements correctly it means that the element is in one position and highlight portion is somewhere during spying in Blue prism  using HTML or AA mode.

can you please help in resolving these kind of issues?

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the html overlay isn't interpreted properly. There's a couple of tricks I use to get the web-elements and the 'spy boxes' to align properly again:

- Window the browser and maximize the browser (mess a bit with the size of the browser's window;
- Zoom in/out (mess a bit with the zoom, go 150%, then 50% and then back to 100%. Not an exact science);
- If the above fails (and re-opening the browser doesn't help either), figure out roughly what the offset is. If this is, say ~50px up, then spying the element 50px above the intended element will still allow the RPA solution to correctly interact with the intended element.

Please refrain from accepting this solution. This is just a workaround, maybe there's a proper solution to this.

Comment: Anecdotally: usually when I observe problems like they're described in the OP, it's the browser's zoom level being set to something other than 100%. If you read the browser automation guide, the browser's zoom MUST be set to 100% in order to spy elements correctly.

Comment: @esqew yea this usually resolves it for me as well, though not always...

Comment: BROWSER ZOOM 100% WORKED FOR ME-   THANKS